# how to remove below the tableView cell in iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I am making an iphone application in which i create input field in first cell so problem is that when app is loaded it shows a line below the textfield in tableView i want to remove that line if we add new row then it does not show line but when row is one it shows line .I have also attached screenshot from the app.

[image]

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 {


  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];


  if(!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
   // cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabelsales.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
    //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }




  for (UIView *subView in cell.subviews)
    {
    if (subView.tag == 2 || subView.tag == 22) 
    {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }
   }



   tableView.backgroundView=nil;


   if(indexPath.section==0){
    tagInputField =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,2,248,30)];



    tagInputField.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    tagInputField.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;

    tagInputField.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    tagInputField.tag = 2;
    tagInputField.delegate = self;
    tagInputField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;





    //[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];



    //[tagInputField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];






    tagInputField.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Myriad-Pro" size:8];
    [tagInputField setText:@"Enter tag here "];
    tagInputField.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];
    [cell addSubview:tagInputField];
    if(tagArray.count >0)
    {

      //  [tagInputField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];





    }
    else {
        //  [tagInputField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];





    }


    return cell;
    }

    if(indexPath.section==1) {
    UIButton *crossButton =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(228, 8, 18, 18)];
    crossButton.tag = 22; //use a tag value that is not used for any other subview
    //crossButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    crossButton.backgroundColor  = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cross.png"]];
    [cell addSubview:crossButton];
    cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Myriad-Pro" size:8];
    cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    cell.textLabel.text =[tagArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [crossButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [tagInputField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

    [tagInputField setFrame:CGRectMake(8,2,240,32)];

    tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];







    [publishButton setFrame:CGRectMake(40,560,250, 50)];

    [descriptionTextImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(48,450,250,90)];






    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is add a empty view in the footer if you are not using it.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];

    return view;
}
```

Another option is to use a UITableViewStyleGrouped style.

-Cong